# Notation for monoidal categories' natural transformations

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

[When reading about *monoidal categories*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+category), I came across this notation for components of natural isomorphisms:

$$
λ:(1⊗(−)) →(−) \\
\lambda_x: 1 ~ \otimes x \to x \\
~\\
ρ:(−)⊗1→(−) \\
\rho_x: x ~\otimes  1 \to x 
$$

And I think I understand what they mean, but their notation confuses me. A natural transformation maps from a functor to another, but this one seems to map from a bifunctor to an object.

I guess this means, that it maps from the bifunctor to the identity functor. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here $\lambda_x$ is a natural transformation between two functors $F$ and $G$.  The first functor $F$ is given on objects by $F(x)=1\otimes x$.  In other words, $F$ is the functor you get from the bifunctor $\otimes$ by fixing the first input to always be $1$.  The second functor $G$ is, as you guessed, the identity functor.